# Connecting moshi to Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, moshi

I use Kotlin in Android Studio. I can not compile the project with the moshi library connected. https://github.com/square/moshi

Tell me, what am I doing wrong ?? I can see in the console:

```
:app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug
:app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug
com/squareup/moshi/JsonReader references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
com/squareup/moshi/CollectionJsonAdapter$1 references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
com/squareup/moshi/JsonAdapter$5 references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
com/squareup/moshi/package-info references unknown class: javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
com/squareup/moshi/ArrayJsonAdapter$1 references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
com/squareup/moshi/AdapterMethodsFactory$1 references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
okio/package-info references unknown class: javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
com/squareup/moshi/Types references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
com/squareup/moshi/JsonAdapter references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
okio/ByteString references unknown class: javax/annotation/Nullable
```

---

top-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lfom.modbuster"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'

    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/LevWi/modbuster-blt/blob/Signals/app/build.gradle

---

proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you set `minifyEnabled true` in debug but `minifyEnabled false` in release. That make no sense. Either set both to `true` or both to `false`.

The second thing is. Do you know what `minifyEnabled` do? It enabled ProGuard in your project. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) for more details.

However. You have two options to fix that issue. Either set `minifyEnabled` to `false` or apply ProGuard in a correct way.

Starting by adding

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

to your `build.gradle`.

Ending by applying [these rules](https://github.com/square/moshi#proguard) in your `proguard-rules.pro`.